# Unity // WebGL builds and streamingAssetsPath

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a Unity build that references a .json file. This file is to be kept in the Streaming Assets folder after the build. The build works great on the desktop when I use the line of code below to call the file in my script (using LitJson):

```
jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/quatData.json");
```

However, when building with WebGL, I get an error in the console that reads:

```
IsolatedStorageException: Could not find a part of the path "/http:/localhost:3333/StreamingAssets/quatData.json".
```

The path in the console is almost the correct location for quatData.json, but I believe that the slash in front of the http would cause the link to fail. Any ideas why this isn't working or why there is a slash after the build?

Comment: The `File` class is meant to work with direct filesystem access, which isn't what you have on a browser-based game. You may want to try web-based access such as the `WWW` class.